A show about a man on the run. Not the Fugitive
This show was about a man who opened the safe in a boardroom while trying to sell a company security. He learned or saw something he shouldn't. So they killed his wife and framed him. He went on the run while trying to hunt them out. They may have been aliens or monsters, not sure. He met a man who lived in a trailer and either blogged or put out a newspaper filled with conspiracy theories. The main character told this man his story and gained a friend and ally. 

So is this the whole plot of the TV show or just the episode?

What was the time period of the show? When did the show originally air (if you know)?

The show centered on the man hunting his wife's killers while trying to avoid being arrested. In one episode he was arrested by a policeman who turned out to be one of the bad guys. So he had to kill the policeman and was also wanted for that.

The man in the trailer had computers so it had to be the 90's or 2000's.

First Wave, (1998):

Reformed thief Cade Foster discovers that aliens are among us in the
  form of genetic clones, intent on enslaving the population. To assess
  the human potential to fight back, they gather data from 117 test
  subjects. When Foster remembers the tests conducted on him, the
  aliens frame him for his wife's murder.
...
Aided by a quirky cyber-journalist, Foster investigates strange occurrences which have ties to Nostradamus' quatrains, hoping to find
  what he needs to forestall the aliens' plans.

